# Парсер курсов валют в базу

Tags: php, mysql, парсер

Ситуация такая - вот код парсера:

```
<?php
include "dbc.php";
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'", $dbcnx);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $dbcnx);

  $date = date("d/m/Y"); // Сегодняшняя дата в необходимом формате
  $link = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=$date"; // Ссылка на XML-файл с курсами валют
  $content = file_get_contents($link); // Скачиваем содержимое страницы
  $dom = new domDocument("1.0", "cp1251"); // Создаём DOM
  $dom->loadXML($content); // Загружаем в DOM XML-документ
  $root = $dom->documentElement; // Берём корневой элемент
  $childs = $root->childNodes; // Получаем список дочерних элементов
  $data = array(); // Набор данных
  for ($i = 0; $i < $childs->length; $i++) {
    $childs_new = $childs->item($i)->childNodes; // Берём дочерние узлы
    for ($j = 0; $j < $childs_new->length; $j++) {
      /* Ищем интересующие нас валюты */
      $el = $childs_new->item($j);
      $code = $el->nodeValue;
      if (($code == "USD") || ($code == "EUR")) $data[] = $childs_new; // Добавляем необходимые валюты в массив
    }
  }
  /* Перебор массива с данными о валютах */
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $list = $data[$i];
    for ($j = 0; $j < $list->length; $j++) {
      $el = $list->item($j);
      /* Выводим курсы валют */


      if ($el->nodeName == "Name") {
        // echo $el->nodeValue;
        if ($el->nodeValue == "Доллар США") $cur = "USD";
        if ($el->nodeValue == "Евро") $cur = "EUR";
        echo $cur;
      }

      elseif ($el->nodeName == "Value") {
        // echo $el->nodeValue."<br>";
        $val = $el->nodeName;
      }

    mysql_query("UPDATE `law_all_currency` SET `$cur` = '$val'");

    }
  }

mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
```

Все до боли понятно, но у меня не получается по-человечески запихнуть значение USD в колонку USD и значение EUR в колонку EUR таблицы "law_all_currency"

**Прошу о помощи. Спасибо заранее!**

Comment: а что значит "по-человечески?"

Comment: И я не знаю, что у вас должно храниться в таблице, но в том виде как у вас написан update он меняет значения поля с именем из $cur на значение из $val во всех записях таблицы, ибо условия выборки записей не указаны

Comment: Значит, чтобы работало. До моих правок код был таким:
      if ($el->nodeName == "Name") {
        echo $el->nodeValue." - ";
      }

      elseif ($el->nodeName == "Value") {
        echo $el->nodeValue."<br>";
      }
Я пока не смог соединить валюту и значение в один запрос АПДЕЙТА

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно показать структуру таблицы law_all_currency и пояснить, какие поля и в каких записях (критерии отбора) необходимо обновлять.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Vm69k08iD0zJ3r
Меняем только ячейки для USD и EUR

Comment: почему вы в базу пишите название нода "value" надо писать заместо $val = $el->nodeName; это $val = $el->nodeValue;

Comment: Ну вот ..я же говорю . проследил.. Спасибо !

Comment: зачем вы `Name` проверяете? у вас же вчера в вопросе в коде была фильтрация по ID валюты, так что вам нужны узлы `<valute id='R01235'>` и  `R01239` и и их дочерние `value`

Comment: Вдобавок, проще будет использовать `XPath` для фильтрации нужных узлов.

Comment: @berTalino Ответ помог???

Comment: Да - http://joxi.ru/gmvbjoyFLBM5am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо писать заместо:

```
$val = $el->nodeName;
```

это

```
$val = $el->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю сюда вариант кода слегка попроще вашего для получения данных, может пригодится.

Для начала получаем курс валют в XML на текущую дату (без параметра):

```
$url = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

Далее используем [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php) для работы.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
```

Поскольку идентификаторы `ID` валют не изменяются, то нам нужно извлечь узлы cо значениями `R01235`и `R01239`. Для этих целей используем [XPath](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) выражение вида `"/ValCurs/Valute[@ID='R01235']/Value"`. Для получения текстового значения узла его необходимо явно или неявно привести к типу `string`:

```
$cfg = ['usd' => 'R01235', 'eur' => 'R01239'];
$data = [];
foreach($cfg as $k => $id){
    $v = (string) $xml->xpath("/ValCurs/Valute[@ID='$id']/Value")[0];
    $data[$k] = floatVal(str_replace(',', '.', $v));
}
```

При необходимости заменяя запятую в значении на нужный нам разделитель.
На выходе имеем массив:

```
Array
(
    [usd] => 59.9533
    [eur] => 63.5445
)
```

Если необходимо использовать [DOM](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php), то код будет следующим:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($content);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml);
foreach($cfg as $k => $id){
    $data[$k] = $xp->query("/ValCurs/Valute[@ID='$id']/Value")->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
```